ROS2 recommended handling of workspace setup.bash
I have heard from some experienced ROS developers that with ROS2 you should not have your workspace setup.bash file already sourced when you are doing a build on repos with some notable changes. This is in line with the tutorial here. Compared to ROS1, this extra step is a bit annoying. In the past when doing a lot of development in one workspace, I would source the workspace setup.bash in my .bashrc file and source it again after builds and never had any issues. I found it makes it easier to launch/test code whenever I want.
Is this a new issue with ROS2, or has it always been a thing? Is there any compelling reason I should change my workflow?

I don't know that much about the topic myself, as I was just sourcing my ws in the .bashrc as you mentioned, but searching a bit deeper I found this issue discussion of 2022.
It seems that in some situations sourcing and building in the same terminal could lead to unintended consequences like packages being overridden from different workspaces. For example, you work with different version of the same packages in different workspaces. You would get errors or unexpected behavior because of using the wrong version.
As far as I'm concerned (and waiting for further information), this is not that bad if you have unique packages that are not going to collide with packages included from the other workspaces.

Yes, as ivrolan pointed out, the problem is related to dependencies and different versions being sourced. I found it easy to just have a singular terminal to source the ros base setup.bash (line inserted in .bashrc) and source manually on the other terminals the underlayed ws. You could use an alias as well to do it briefly.

The linked issue gives a great overview. From my reading, it seems that for the common usecase (apt installed ROS2 with one overlaid workspace [e.g. ros2_ws]) my workflow is acceptable, but when you do a source build/overlay of apt installed packages and/or are using more than 1 overlay workspace you invite issues unless you do the separate build terminal suggested in the tutorial (no setup.bash/local_setup.bash sourcing).

I had more or less the same question, see here.
Bottom line is the following:

install/setup.bash extends the environment with the environment of other prefix paths which were sourced when this file [i.e. setup.bash] was generated as well as all packages contained in this prefix path.

So you need to be careful, e.g. if you recompile the ROS 2 source tree in the same terminal where you previously sourced some other workspaces, than the setup.bash of your ROS 2 build will suddenly include the COLCON_PREFIX_PATH of those other workspaces as well.
The upside of this is that you can just source your workspace and all other necessary workspaces (e.g. ROS, Gazebo, possible other packages, etc) will be auto-sourced.
The downside is that you have to be careful in which terminal to build what...
The alternative is to use install/local_setup.bash instead.
If this really bugs you and/or is a showstopper, I think it might be worthwile to investigate the use of Docker images to set up a modular environment.
Another idea is to use some .bashrc logic to check COLCON_PREFIX_PATH before each invocation of colcon, and issue a warning with a Continue? Y/N prompt.

This a good point, if a bit tangential. It seems to me that the cause of the issue for most people is this (source):
"..do any packages in the underlay depend on the ones being overridden, but are themselves not rebuilt? If so, API or ABI changes in the re-built subset can lead to undefined behavior."

I strongly agree with the point about docker. Although this is a bit off-topic, but the modularity provided by being able to mount selected workspaces as volumes and then have them interact with each other in a sandbox environment saves a lot of head scratching time while debugging.
